# When should we align our data and when does the compiler do it for us?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, assembly, optimization

Alignment of data (and instructions) is still fairly critical to high performance computing, according to the Intel optimization manuals.

I am aware we must align data ourselves to avoid false sharing (two threads accessing two variables within same cache line) because the compiler cannot possibly know our threading model.

However, does GCC perform any other alignments/what alignments does it not do/what alignments must we do ourselves for performance?

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/, but your question is too broad.

Comment: Maybe the question should be "When should we align our data and when does the compiler do it for us?"

Comment: what about alignment to use SIMD instructions? or when you want to convert between types in other type of processors (MIPS will break if you try to store in a non aligned address)

Comment: @JamesPoag I will change it to that

Comment: @dlavila I was aware of that, but I'm more interested in non-intrinsic usage.

Comment: whenever you use a pointer/struct across compile domains...which is...never.  The compiler should be doing what it can to keep things sane by default, esp for platforms that fault on alignment errors.   What do you see when you create structs with various length items ideally smaller first, does your compiler align them by using padding without any compiler specific direction?